# Viability of heated plants via fission as a power source

Tags: science-based, biology, bio-mechanics

This is something I haven't seen before, so it might not be viable, but still, I'd like to put it out there

A biological organism takes in radioactive material, encourages it to undergo fission, the various charged products are spit out, and heat up in the process creating a biological fission reactor. That is fuel rods, or the central radiation pile being replaced with a biological system. The question is then, how viable is it, if it is what biological processes and/or organisms might be used to achieve this.

Comment: See https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15136/how-could-a-plant-generate-harmful-only-to-other-species-radiation-or-similar

Comment: Please note that we do not (yet) have a formal policy concerning "review my idea" questions. Is this viable? Not using today's technology nor by the extension of any science we're aware of... but that doesn't mean anything on a website devoted to helping you develop and consistently use rules for an imaginary world of your own creation. The idea is cool and would be great in a story... why does it matter if it's viable? Do you expect someone to challenge your idea as "unrealistic?" Such a judgement would be contrary to more than a century of science fiction.

Comment: Isaac Asmimov's Pâté de Foie Gras is a short story where a goose produced golden eggs via catalyzed nuclear transformations. Not directly equivalent, and not plausible science either, but might be worth as a comparison story by one of the classic SF masters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A biological organism takes in radioactive material, encourages it to undergo fission

This seems the most problematic part: radioactive material is just material with an unstable nucleus which will decay into a more stable one, following the alpha, beta or gamma decay, while a fissile material is a nucleus which, when hit by a neutron, will break in two releasing energy.

The only "encouragement" possible is therefore to supply thermal neutrons to a batch of fissile material.

- Fissile material is scarce: if it was so abundant that an organism could evolve to use it, it would probably turn its location into a blowing up nuke before the above mentioned organism could evolve.
- Producing thermal neutrons is not easy: you need a neutron source and a moderator.

While it's true that life can find a way, don't forget that finding a way it's easier when statistically favorable: a scarce material with a difficult way to make it produce energy seems like a very uphill evolutionary path.

Answer (score 2):

### Sorry, not plausible

Here on earth, the options for fissile materials with any significant abundance is very limited. U-235. List ends. For fertile materials that can be bred, Th-233 and U-238. That's it. These are heavy metals with significant chemical toxicity, but this is the least of your problems.

There is no known way to catalyze fission reactions other than using free neutrons. Such isotopes exist, but they are not really available for a natural process because of their rarity (short half lives). Portable neutron generators in commercial use nuclear reactors, or particle accelerators to get the required isotopes. There is another route, combine an alpha emitter and a target that when hit by an alpha, emits a neutron. But the same kind of problems with rarity will still exist.

Radiation sources inside a living being are a bad idea. You won't be able to tightly focus the neutron beam that lives in your animal to just strike your nuclear material, neutrons will fly in all directions destroying you from within.

How do we create nuclear reactors then. By concentrating fissile materials into sufficient volume so that the reaction can be made critical - you need kilos of even U-235 (the easiest route) to make a reactor.

Smaller quantities of material suitable for use in Radioisotope Thermoelectric Generator (RTG) would theoretically be suitable as a heat source for biologic systems (no fission involved). But, you still have scarcity issues for these isotopes. As well as the radiation damage that would kill your animal.

Write the story if like, but the science will not be plausible. A lot of SF mixes in fantasy elements, often via the agency of technobabble.